# How to receive notification data after tapping the notifcation while the app is in background?

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic3

Considering my app is running background or is off, when I receive a notification and tap on it, my app opens but I don’t receive any data from that notification.

Here is the piece of code I’m using :

```
initPushNotification() {
        if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            console.warn('Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device');
            return;
        }
        const options: PushOptions = {
            android: {
                senderID: MY_SENDER_ID
            },
            ios: {
                alert: 'true',
                badge: false,
                sound: 'true'
            },
            windows: {}
        };
        const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

        pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {             
            // send notification token to server
            // ...
        });

        pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.notificationService.display(data);
        });

        pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin' + error));
    }
```

I’m expecting to get log from that part but I don’t get anything :

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.notificationService.display(data);
        });
```

NB : I only encounter the problem with Android, it’s working fine with iOS.

I’m using

```
“@angular/*”: “5.0.0”,
"@ionic-native/push": “4.5.2”,
“cordova-plugin-device”: “1.1.7”,
“cordova-plugin-fcm”: “2.1.2”,
```

I’ve spent hours browsing Ionic docs and Stack but I don’t have ideas anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit :**
Here is my json message data :

```
{
 "to" : "fDb5ibGYPdE:APA91bFYVW4hb9URujxcAXQIqxEs58vNOoJLXH8bNQW7sKS2ZN",
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "great match!!!!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "moduleFunctionalId": "filInfo",
 "jsonData": "{id:3884}",
 "additionalData":"aa"
 },
 "data" : {
 "body" : "great match",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "moduleFunctionalId": "filInfo",
 "jsonData": "{id:3884}",
 "additionalData":"bb"
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior (as you've seen in the documentation). If you're using a notification-only message payload (which you are), onMessageReceived() will only be called if your app is in foreground, if not, the System Tray will be receiving it.

The data being referred to in (emphasis mine):

In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

is the data message payload (See Message Types).

You'll have to send a payload with both notification and data. Like so:

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
    },
  "data": {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
  }
}
```

For more details please refer below link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Please check your message json which is look like same as above or not.if not same then please make it like same. And after check with the same hope it works for you.

If it's work then please close this questions.And if you have any doubt then please comment below post.i will help you.

Comment: Thanks @jyubin for your answer. I added my json message data in the first post. Is anything wrong about it ?

Comment: Firebase which handles notification sending technique so when GCM is there then it's working properly but FCM update it's mechanism.

Comment: what is problem?? have you checked your json data and please compare into above link data tray

Comment: please check my updated link into answers which helps you  and solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake by reading this [post from Github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1506).

Instead of sending

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
    },
  "data": {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
  }
}
```

I have to send

```
{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "data": {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
  }
}
```

and I now retrieve my data.